# Redirecting Apache by Geo/Country IP

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Do any of you folks do redirection by IP (within Apache) for people coming
to your website from different countries?

What do ye use? mod_geoip and/or a whole pile of mod_rewrite rules?
Is mod_geoip reliable/well-performing/accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to use mod_geoip but recently dumped Apache for [Cherokee](http://www.cherokee-project.com/) (which has its own GEOIP logic).

I can't say I've had any performance problems with either but Cherokee is definitely easier to get set up.

Accuracy is pretty spot on but (obviously) neither cannot tell if somebody is browsing through a transparent proxy in another country.